# Sql query issue on select stmt

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below I have the tables:`Documents`, `Users` and `DocumentUserMapping`.
`Documents` table has the columns `userid` `documentid` and `documentname`.
`Users` table has `userid` `username`.
`DocumentUserMapping` table has `documentid` and `userid`.

I will pass `userid` and I need to get all `documentname` for that `userid` from documents table and when I enter the `userid` and `Documentid` in `Documentusermapping`  from document table that `docid`, `document name`  from documents should not display.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Doc.DocumentID, Doc.DocumentName FROM Documents Doc  

 WHERE   Doc.DocumentID NOT IN (SELECT DocumentID FROM DocumentUserMapping DUM WHERE UserID = @i_UserID)  AND Doc.DocumentID NOT IN (@i_UserID)     

 SELECT DUM.UserID, P1.UserLoginID , DUM.DocumentID, P2.DocumentName, DUM.ViewDoc, DUM.EditDoc FROM DocumentUserMapping DUM    
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Users P1 ON P1.UserID = DUM.UserID    
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Documents P2 ON P2.DocumentID = DUM.DocumentID     
    WHERE DUM.UserID = @i_UserID

passing userid=2

USERiD Username
1       AAA

Documents table
Docid,Doc name userid
1         xxx      2
2         yyy      2

Document usermap

USERiD Docid
1         3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Documents D INNER JOIN
Users U ON D.UserID = U.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
DocumentUserMapping DUM ON D.DocumentID = DUM.DocumentID AND D.UserID = DUM.UserID
WHERE DUM.DocumentID IS NULL AND D.UserID = @UserID
```

You can refer to what I have done in SQL Fiddler to figure out your problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/397d7/6